# Cannot compile my project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, gac

So i am working on ASP.NET project. I was trying to debug a wierd issues that I couldn't figure out. I decided to download source code for MVC and debug with that. Here is what happened.

1. I downloaded and compiled the mvc solution from codeplex.
2. I removed reference to MVC from my own project and added a reference to the source code csproj file
3. Meanwhile I figured out what was actual issues so decided to go back and remove source code csproj file.
4. I added back C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll in reference

Now when I try to run project I get following error. I deleted and renamed root folder under c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files, but when I run project this folder get created again and complaint about the same error.

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\037dc5b9\7cd3238e\App_Web_logon.cshtml.9cf88e2b.y6cgf4sv.0.cs(41): error CS0433: The type 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\037dc5b9\7cd3238e\assembly\dl3\527f6213\51a90210_63d1cc01\System.Web.Mvc.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll'

Comment: well problem is the error is about MVC dll that exists in two locations

Comment: AS i said in question, i have deleted the whole root folder under .NET framwork\Temporary ASP.NET. However I am n ot sure if deleting any file from GAC is a good idea

Comment: Don't delete your Web.Mvc.dll file from Microsoft.NET\assembly unless you want to manually download and replace it.

Comment: yeah i know its not a good idea. Actually whoever gave that suggestion now deleted those comments :)

Comment: Check out an earlier version in your source control. Fix known bug.

Comment: @David: not sure what you mean by "Fix known bug"? I already have rolled back any of my changes from source control. The same codebase works fine on other developers machines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleting the bin folder solved the problem. Apparently doing a "Clean Solution"/"Rebuild solution" did not remove system dlls (for good reasons I think). Anyways thanks for those who commented on my question.